# How to send multiple data to PrinterShare Intent?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, printing

## Scenario:

I have a android application that uses PrinterShare to print PDF files, selecting one each time to print.

## Question:

How to do to select some PDF files and then, when the user clicks "Print", the app sends all the selected PDF files as data to the PrinterShare Intent?

Can i do it?

At the moment, i can only send one per time, this way:

```java
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare");    
i.setType("application/pdf");
i.setDataAndType("file.pdf", "application/pdf");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: You would need to ask the authors of `com.dynamixsoftware.printershare` what they support.

Comment: I already did it, but i got no response. by the way, i am hoping someone here did uses this app.